# Hide div initially in jquery clone

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I am looping a div on button click. But what I need is to hide the .loop div initially and display it on button click.

Currently it is clone is happening perfectly, only thing I  need is,not to show the div.loop  initially. Show only button by default.

here is my current code and **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UPEmeMo/2/edit)**

```
clicks = 0;
$('button').on('click', function () {
    if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
        clicks++;
        newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
        $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clicks = 0;
$('button').on('click', function () {
  $('div.loop').show();
    if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
        clicks++;
        if(clicks>1){
            alert("more 1");
            newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
        });
        }
        else{
          alert("asd");
        newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).appendTo(".container");
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
        });


    }

    }
});
```

Replace and try this code with yours..Hope this is what you needed..

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UPEmeMo/3/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options here. You might hide your template with CSS initially, and then on clone, remove the CSS hiding the clone. Another option is to create your "loop" element entirely with JavaScript, and attach it later.

**[Demo Option 1](http://jsbin.com/odabUji/1/edit)** - Use a hide class on the first div.loop template, remove the class on clone using `.removeClass()`.

**[Demo Option 2](http://jsbin.com/IDAjAqi/1/edit)** - Use a template created in jQuery instead of selecting a shell element.

Note: I've updated the name attribute of `first name` to `first_name`.

Comment: @user1145009, You're correct. I've updated the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/odabUji/2/edit) to limit to 5 rows, replicating the initial user experience. Bear in mind that submitting a form in this way will submit 6 rows, which is probably not suitable. Option 2 is the better choice.